# Pentaho convert string to integer with decimal point

Tags: string, format, pentaho, mask, kettle

I am importing text values into a transformation using a Fixed Width input step.  Everything is coming in as a string.  I want to convert some of the string values to integers with a decimal point at a specified spot.  Here are some examples of the before (left hand side) and expected results (right hand side):

```
00289 --> 0028.9
01109 --> 0110.9
003201 --> 0032.01
```

I've tried numerous combinations of the Format mask in a Select Values step  (meta data tab) but I can't get the values I'm looking for.

Can you anyone tell me what combination I can try for* Type/Length/Precision/Format/Encoding/Decimal/Group* attributes for these fields to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried another step the reach your goal? You can try to use e.g. `User Defined Java Expression` setting it in this way:

- **Java expression:** `new java.math.BigDecimal(text.substring(0,4) + "." + text.substring(4,text.length()))`
- **Value type:** BigNumber

But this will convert your input to:

```
00289 --> 28.9
01109 --> 110.9
003201 --> 32.01
```

Because its output is `BigNumber` format. `BigNumber` or `Number` format can be used for decimal numbers. You cannot use `Integer` for decimals because it has no decimal part.

If you want a `String` output leave out the `new java.math.BigDecimal()` part from the expression above and set Value type to `String`. It will produce these results:

```
00289 --> 0028.9
01109 --> 0110.9
003201 --> 0032.01
```

This is the one suggestion. Of course there are another ways of how to reach your goal.